# Powershell - let user choose from list of January through December

Tags: powershell

I'm not a great scripter, and I'm lost in translation...maybe I'm doing this completely wrong...

I'm building a script and I want the user to pick from a list of choices, specifically the month of the year.  This result would then be used later in the script.

Here's the snippet:

```
$optionQuit = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "Quit", "Quit"
$option1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "01-January", "01-January OU"
$option2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "02-February", "02-February OU"
$option3 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "03-March", "03-March OU"
$option4 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "04-April", "04-April OU"
$option5 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "05-May", "05-May OU"
$option6 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "06-June", "06-June OU"
$option7 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "07-July", "07-July OU"
$option8 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "08-August", "08-August OU"
$option9 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "09-September", "09-September OU"
$option10 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "10-October", "10-October OU"
$option11 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "11-November", "11-November OU"
$option12 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "12-December", "12-December OU"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($optionQuit, $option1, $option2, $option3, $option4. $option5, $option6, $option7, $option8, $option9, $option10, $option11, $option12)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, [int[]](0))
```

However, I keep getting an error:

> ERROR: Exception calling "PromptForChoice" with "4" argument(s):
>   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   TestingMenu.ps1 (31, 1): ERROR: At Line: 31 char: 1 ERROR: + $result =
>   $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, [int[] ... ERROR:
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
>   MethodInvocationException ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   NullReferenceException ERROR:

I'm not sure what I'm missing...and I'm likely making this more complicated than need be...but the end variable $result should be something like "04-April" for instance.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: You should be sending a `Collection`, not an array.  Your `ChoiceDescription[]` is an array.  Take a look at the example on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: With so many selections, you might consider refactoring your code so that something like:
$result = $options | Out-GridView -Title "Select an item" -OutputMode Single
gives you the desired behavior.

Comment: @gravity Array can be converted to `Collection` implicitly, because `Collection` have [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx) and single dimension zero-based array implement generic version of `IList`.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Ah, OK.  Thank you!  So the declaration (as defined above) _does_, in fact, create the collection appropriately?  Sidenote: I'm surprised I missed the '.' vs ',' as well.

Comment: @KoryGill - thank you...I think this is a good idea and gives me the single output into $result I need.

Comment: @gravity Yes, PowerShell create the collection for you. With fix, proposed by HeXDeMoN, OP code should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your options variable, you have a period instead of a comma after $option4.

Fix that and it should work.

```
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($optionQuit, $option1, $option2, $option3, $option4, $option5, $option6, $option7, $option8, $option9, $option10, $option11, $option12)
```

Answer (score 5):

This variant works and isn't that redundant. Without marking the letter to choose with an & ampersand choice makes no sense

```
# C:\Test\Choose-CUI.ps1
$choices=@(
  ("&Quit","Quit"),
  ("0&1-January","01-January OU"),
  ("0&2-February","02-February OU"),
  ("0&3-March","03-March OU"),
  ("0&4-April","04-April OU"),
  ("0&5-May","05-May OU"),
  ("0&6-June","06-June OU"),
  ("0&7-July","07-July OU"),
  ("0&8-August","08-August OU"),
  ("0&9-September","09-September OU"),
  ("1&0-October","10-October OU"),
  ("11-&November","11-November OU"),
  ("12-&December","12-December OU")
)
$choicedesc = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]
for($i=0; $i -lt $choices.length; $i++){
  $choicedesc.Add((New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription $choices[$i] ) ) }
$Host.ui.PromptForChoice($caption, $message, $choicedesc, $default)
```

Has this output

```
PS C:\Test> .\Choose-CUI.ps1
[Q] Quit
[1] 01-January
[2] 02-February
[3] 03-March
[4] 04-April
[5] 05-May
[6] 06-June
[7] 07-July

[8] 08-August
[9] 09-September
[0] 10-October
[N] 11-November
[D] 12-December
[?] Help
Choice[0]:
```

Comment: Thank you @LotPings for cleaning up my code and helping me learn.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer (by @user681141) said, but perhaps a little more concise;
you can just pipe the array into `ForEach-Object`, which is aliased as `%`:

```
$choices = @(
  ("&Quit",        "Quit"),
  ("0&1-January",  "01-January OU"),
  ("0&2-February", "02-February OU"),
  ("0&3-March",    "03-March OU"),
  # etc...
) | % { New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription $_ }

$Host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $choices, $default)
```